# update data in two columns using the first column with plsql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have table of two columns the first one with data  01 0 1 0 0 0 the second one full with description  i want to replace data with another data if it was 0 
so i did something like that

```
begin
      select BRA_CODE , BRA_DESC
        from REQUESTS 
   loop
      update REQUESTS
         set BRA_DESC = 'ajman'
                where BRA_CODE = 0;
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: and what's your problem in details...?

Comment: my problem it was a view from two tables now i have to update one column regards from another column from the other table

Comment: Can you give us the sql for the view ?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW REQUESTS
(

   BRA_CODE,
   BRA_DESC,

)
   BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS
   SELECT 
          TO_CHAR (AID.BEK_BRA_CODE) BRANCHE_CODE,
          DECODE ('AR', 'AR', BRANCHE.Arabic_Value, BRANCHE.VALUE)
             BRANCH_DESC,
     FROM D_REQUESTS AID
          LEFT JOIN FND_LOOKUP_VALUES BRANCHE
             ON (    BRANCHE.LOOKUP_CODE = AID.BEK_BRANCHES_CODE
                 AND BRANCHE.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'CASES_BRANCH')

Comment: Hi, can you give more details? what are the tables and columns, sample data and expected output?

Comment: look i did something like that
    UPDATE LOOKUP_VALUES 
    SET ARABIC_VALUE = 'ajman'
    WHERE (select bb.C_VALUE
    from LOOKUP_VALUES bb join REQUESTS RQ
    on( bb.LOOKUP_CODE = RQ.BRANCHES_CODE 
    AND bb.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'CASES_BRANCH')and
    LOOKUP_CODE = 0);
and its also not working

Answer (score 0):

Well, `UPDATE` you wrote seems to be all you need and is the fastest way to do it.

Why would you want to write & use slower PL/SQL? Row-by-row will be slow-by-slow, no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: first thanks for answering my question
but i need to know is my code correct ?

Comment: Which one? The whole code you posted? No, it is not correct. Run it and you'll see.